# linux device which don't allow to write on it

Tags: linux, bash

I have a script which write some warnings to separate file (it's name is passed as an argument). I want to make this script fail if there is a warning.

So, I need to pass some file name which must raise an error if someone try to write there.
I want to use some more or less idiomatic name (to include it to man page of my script).

So, let say my script is

```
# myScript.sh
echo "Hello" > $1
```

If I call it with

```
./myScript.sh /dev/stdin
```

it is not fail because /dev/stdin is not read-only device (surprisingly!)
After

```
./myScript.sh /
```

it is failed, as I want it (because / is a directory, you can't write there). But is is not idiomatic.

Is there some pretty way to do it?

Comment: From man bash `-w file :
              True if file exists and is writable.`

Comment: no, I need idiomatic read-only device or file name! Something like /dev/null, but read-only:)

Answer (score 1):

```
if [ -w "$1" ]
then
   echo "$Hello" > "$1" # Mind the double-quotes
fi
```

is what you're looking for. Below would even be better in case you've only
one argument.

```
if [ -w "$*" ]
then
   echo "$Hello" > "$*" # Mind the double-quotes
fi
```

`$*` is used to accommodate nonstandard file names. `"$*"` combines multiple arguments into a single word. Check [[ this ]](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Bash_Shell_Scripting).

Comment: Huh?  I don't see how `"$*"` would be "better" in any way.  If the user passes in multiple files, the way to cope is `for f in "$@"; do if [ -w "$f" ]; ` etc.

Comment: @tripleee : The user has only one argument here as confirmed in the question.. Otherwise perfectly in agreement with you..